# How to change the color of the navigation bar in more than one table view controller

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of the table view navigation bar in multiple table views. The table views are all connected to a navigation controller. For example, I want one navigation bar to be blue, but another to be red. I have tried the code below in the AppDelegate.m file, but it just changes all the navigation bars to the same color. Is there anywhere else I could place this code to change the color in specific places. I've heard that I need to create new files, but I don't know where to place the code, or what code to use in the new files. I am somewhat new to this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];`

Comment: If you don't need to do it programmatically why not just set all the bar tints within storyboard?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give me that option. It only allows me to change the title, prompt, and back button.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, in your table view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // set navigation bar's tint color when being shown
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

You can add a property to make the view controller re-usable. Typically, you'd set the property in the `prepareForSegue` method of the pushing view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *toolbarTintColor;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.toolbarTintColor) {
        self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = self.toolbarTintColor;
    }
}
```

And finally, another approach is to implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol and set the color in `willShowViewController`:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIColor *barTintColor = ...// your logic for determining the color for the given controller
    navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = barTintColor;
}
```

You can do this in the pushing view controller if, for some reason, you don't want to do it in `viewWillAppear` of the pushed view controller.

Comment: So will I need to make a new class for every view controller?

Comment: Not necessarily (but I can't imagine why you'd ever use a base view controller class without subclassing). I added some additional possibilities to my answer.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to Xcode, so I don't understand subclassing or what it is.

Comment: You're going to need to write code to build an iOS app and subclasses are primarily where you'll put your code. So I would suggest you read a beginner-level object oriented programming book.

Comment: There a bug with this method: if you swipe a view controller from left to right (the "back" gesture) but then stop halfway and slide back (so the current view controller is not popped), then the navigation bar will be set to the color of the view that you almost popped to. Haven't been able to find a workaround yet.